# Reference a dictionary within itself

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to get a value from a dictionary entry, within that same dictionary?
I'd like to build up a list of directories whilst referencing previously added directories..

```
common_dirs = {
    'root': '/var/tmp',
    'java_path': os.path.join(dict.get('root'), 'java'),
    'application_path': os.path.join(dict.get('java_path'), 'my_app')
}
```

Comment: Instant -2 ..?? Is it really that bad ?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're shadowing the built in name here. And two, no, you can't because the name doesn't exist until it's created.

Comment: You already know that it's `'/var/tmp'`

Comment: I understand that it's not created, hence me looking for a solution and pointing that out within the question.. the question is, can it be referenced using some internal command?

Comment: I think you'll want to first create the dictionary by saying `dict = {}`, and then add values to it.

Comment: @tehjoker No, it cannot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not update the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'root': '/var/tmp'}
my_dict.update({'file': os.path.join(my_dict.get('root'), 'file')})
```

Don't use `dict` as a name. You may need the real `dict` builtin later on.

Comment: Why even use update? Just do `my_dict['file'] = os.path.join(my_dict.get('root'), 'file')`

Comment: @MorganThrapp It's the same. Just needed my approach to match OP's question by using as many `{}` as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

No. At the point at which you are filling in the dictionary initializer, the dictionary does not exist, so you cannot reference it!

But in principle there is no reason why a dictionary cannot contain itself as one of the values, as the other answers explain, but you just can't refer to it in its own initializer `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a class instead of a dictionary:

```
import os

class Paths:
    def __init__(self, root, filename):
        self.root = root
        self.file = os.path.join(self.root, filename)

root = '/var/tmp'
filename = 'file'

p = Paths(root, filename)
print(p.file)
# /var/tmp/file
```

Comment: That's some crazy overkill, and could potentially break if the rest of OP's code is expecting a dictionary.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Probably, but that doesn't mean they couldn't be passed in dynamically, assuming this is a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Fair enough, I edited the response to show that. I do agree that a class is overkill in all likelihood though!