# python dictionary key pointing to value of another key in the same dictionary

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary that has the below format

```
data = {  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': 'value3'
}
```

I want this `key3` value to point to the value of `key1`.
what i tried so far is 
`'key3': key1['value1']` or `'key3': data['key1']` and both of them seem to be invalid syntaxes.

Comment: You can't reference the dictionary from within itself while constructing it as it doesn't exist as an object yet...

Comment: Also - when you say *I want this key3 value to point to the value of key1* - did you expect when you changed the value of `key1` the accessing `key3` would give you the updated value or the old value?

Comment: @JonClements i expect the value of `key3` to change when `key1` changes

Comment: Possible duplication :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254969/reference-a-dictionary-within-itself

Comment: Also - you'd need to be remarkably wary of cyclic references... if key3 should retrieve the value of key1's value, but accessing key1 tries to return the value of key3...

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't support pointers like C/C++ does, but you *could* use lists to serve as references. To access the value, you'd index into the first element of the list.

```
data = {
  'key1': ['value1']
}

data['key3'] = data['key1']     #  copy the list by reference
print(f"Old: {data['key3'][0]}, {data['key3'][0] == data['key1'][0]}")

data['key1'][0] = 'new-value'   #  this will modify the value from data['key3'] as well    
print(f"New: {data['key3'][0]}, {data['key3'][0] == data['key1'][0]}")
```

Output:

```
Old: value1, True
New: new-value, True
```

Note that, this assumes that you're fully aware of which values act as "pointers" and which ones don't.

For example,

```
data = {
  'key1': ['pointer-list'],    # should act as a "pointer"
  'key2': ['normal', 'list']   # should act as a normal list
}

data['key3'] = data['key1']    # copy list by reference
data['key1'][0] = 'new-value'  # propogate new value to other references

data['key4'] = data['key2']    # oops – copy list by reference
data['key2'][0] = 'new-value'  # oops – data['key2'] should act as a normal list but
                               # the new value is propogated to data['key4'] as well
```

To deal with this issue, [clone or copy the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) instead.

```
import copy
data['key4'] = copy.copy(data['key2'])

# data['key4'] = copy.deepcopy(data['key2']) # if the value contains nested lists
# data['key4'] = data['key2'].copy()   # another way
```

Comment: You have to know to check if it's a list though... and then if lists are valid values, then...

Comment: @JonClements As in... before the value is set (e.g. checking before `data['key1'][0] = 'new_value'`)? I don't quite understand the other part, can you elaborate a bit more? :D

Comment: If I access `key1` directly... I have to *know* it's actual value is the string `value1` and it's *actual* value isn't really a 1-element list... eg: how do I know the difference between it's actually a single element list and not just a single element list because it's being shared?

Comment: @JonClements Hmm... I was assuming that the OP will know which lists serve as  "pointers" and which lists serve as "lists". If there's a dynamic spin to it... then I think your concern is entirely valid.

Comment: A dynamic work around would be a custom dict-like object that only contains values that references another dict, and that dict contains the real values, eg: `{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 1}` and that proxies all operations to the real dict such as `{1: 'value1', 2: 'value2'}`...

Comment: I suppose another consideration is what should the behaviour of `del data['key1']` have... should `key3` be keeping that object alive or since the value of what *it held* is gone, should `key3` now not have a value? :)

Comment: I suppose what you could do here is make *everything* a list and *always* make sure to access the first element... that way the ambiguity is gone.

Comment: @Jon I'm tempted to say "These considerations are left as an exercise for the reader." :P Good points, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data = { 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3' }

data['key3'] = data['key1']

print(data)
```

Prints out:

```
{'key3': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```